# Can I differentiate a Slack display name from a Slack ID?

Tags: slack, slack-api

I'm integrating my software with the Slack API, and I would like to allow the user to configure the Slack settings by writing either the "display name" or the "user ID".

I would like to use an heuristic to differentiate user names from user ids. I read the following in the [Slack documentation](https://api.slack.com/types/user):

> id - this user's ID, which might start with U or W; IDs beginning with
>   U are unique only to a workspace. IDs beginning with W are unique for
>   an entire Enterprise Grid organization and may represent the user on
>   multiple workspaces within it.

Taking a look to a Slack ID, for example (`W012A3CDE`), it seems that it fits the following specs:

- Starts with "U" or "W" *(confirmed by the documentation)*
- Has no lowercase chars *(pretty sure of this)*
- Has at least 1 number *(not sure -> need to confirm)*
- Has 9 chars length *(not sure -> need to confirm)*

If all above are true, I would not be difficult to differentiate the user name from id, and even in an ambiguity case, I would allow to use `@` to resolve the ambiguity.

So my question is: **Is there any public spec about how Slack user IDs are?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I finally found the public Slack regexp used for the user ID:

https://github.com/slackapi/slack-api-specs/blob/master/web-api/slack_web_openapi_v2.json#L106

```
    "defs_user_id": {
        "pattern": "^[UW][A-Z0-9]{8}$",
        "title": "User ID",
        "type": "string"
    },
```